# SPOJ GENERAL: sorting by swaps of distance k

Tags: c++, algorithm, programming-challenge, sorting, time-limit-exceeded

I have been trying to solve this [simple problem on SPOJ](http://br.spoj.com/problems/GENERAL/) for quite some time now, but I keep on getting TLE (Time limit exceeded) for some reason.

Since the problem is in Portuguese, a brief description of the problem is like this (without the story):

> You are given an array of size *N*, you have to arrange the array in
>   ascending order, such that an element can only be swapped with
>   elements which are at a distance *k* from it. If the array can be
>   sorted then print the number of swaps required to arrange them in
>   ascending order, if it cannot be sorted print *impossivel*.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
int a[100005];
int main() {
    int t;
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d", &t); //number of test cases
    while(t--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
        bool result = true;
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }

        for(int i = n; i > 0; i = i - k) {
            int j = 0;
            for( ; j < i - k; j++) {
                if(a[j] > a[j + k]) {
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + k];
                    a[j + k] = temp;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            for( ; j < i - 1; j++) {
                if(a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!result)
                break;
        }
        if(result)
            printf("%d\n", count);
        else
            printf("impossivel\n");
    }
}
```

My logic : I perform **N/k** iterations on the array. I initialize the loop variable **i** to **N**. In each iteration I check **i-k** elements with the element at a distance **k** from it, if they are to be swapped then I swap them and increment the number of swaps needed, else I do nothing. Then I check the elements from **i-k** to **i**, if they are in ascending order, if not I break the loop and print "impossivel", else I change **i** to **i-k** and again perform the loop. By my logic after every iteration the last **k** elements will be in ascending order, if is possible to sort them, since at every step I move the elements which are greater to the right.

Does this seem correct to you? How can optimize this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code can be optimized a little by below changes.

Replace this

```
        for( ; j < i - k; j++) {
            if(a[j] > a[j + k]) {
                int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + k];
                a[j + k] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }

        for( ; j < i - 1; j++) {
            if(a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!result)
            break;
```

By

```
        int  j = i-k;
        int x = 0;
        int tmp[i/k]; // Do check for i==0 here 
        for(int j = i; j >= 0; j -= k){
            tmp[x] = a[j];  
            x++;
        }
        sort(tmp);
        for(int j = i; j >= 0; j -= k){
             a[j] = tmp[x]; x--; 
        }
```

Add a check outside the main loop if its sorted or not. 
But still this will be in order of \$O(N*KlogK)\$ which in worst cases \$O(N^2logN)\$. You might still get the TLE with that.

We can solve this in \$O(NlogN)\$. Trying thinking of solution in which you sort this `a` keeping original indexes of each element. Then calculate the number of swap by comparing the old index with new one.